# Retrieve SQL Azure service levels for all databases on a server via SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Prior to upgrading to SQL Azure V12, I was able to get the service level (S1, S2, P1, P2, etc.) of all databases on a SQL Azure database server by running the following query in the master database:

```
SELECT db.name DatabaseName, ru.sku AS ServiceTier, 
    slo.name AS ServiceLevel, ru.storage_in_megabytes AS StorageInMB, 
    ru.[time] ResourceUsageDateTime
FROM sys.databases db
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.slo_database_objectives dbslo ON (dbslo.database_id = db.database_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.slo_service_objectives slo ON (slo.objective_id = dbslo.configured_objective_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.resource_usage ru ON (ru.database_name = db.name)
WHERE
    ru.[time] = (SELECT MAX([time]) FROM sys.resource_usage);
```

However, this now returns an error saying:
"Invalid object name 'dbo.slo_database_objectives'."

Does anyone know of another way to do this via a SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query on the database:

```
select DATABASEPROPERTYEX(db_name(),'serviceobjective') serviceobjective, 
   DATABASEPROPERTYEX(db_name(),'serviceobjectiveid') serviceobjectiveId, 
   DATABASEPROPERTYEX(db_name(),'edition') edition
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's working again:

```
SELECT  
    d.name,   
    slo.*    
FROM sys.databases d
JOIN sys.database_service_objectives slo    
    ON d.database_id = slo.database_id;
```